# Epub: Start block on next page if it can't fit on current page

Tags: epub, ibooks

Is there a way in an epub file to say that a block should not be split among multiple pages, so that if the current page don't have enough room to show the block, then the block should start on the next page, instead of starting on the current page, and then spill over to the next page.

If this is not possible in general, a solution which work in ibooks and which don't cause problems in other readers are also useful :-}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't played with them myself, but you might want to take a look at the .css widows and orphans styles. They are supported by the 2.0.1 spec [here](http://idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPS_2.0.1_draft.htm#Section3.3) (scroll down to the paged media section). Setting the number high enough on your paragraph style might do the trick.

Comment: That seems like the correct way to do it. But ibooks don't support it so I used the hack described at http://www.pigsgourdsandwikis.com/2010/06/goodbye-widows-and-orphans-or-yes-you.html instead :{

Comment: Hey, whatever works. :-) Paged media is something that epub viewers in general don't do very well. Hopefully that changes as they start supporting the 3.0 spec.

Answer (score 0):

Use `page-break-inside: avoid;`. However, as others mentioned, you should not expect this to work on every platform. The only absolutely fool-proof way to get something to start on a new page on all readers is to place it in a separate XHTML file.